# Ask Poisson distribution with random parameters

Tags: statistics

let $X_i$ denote the quantity that captures the number
of times the word *however* appears in the i-th article. You also count the length of each article in your sample, $(y_1, ..., y_n)$.
Let’s assume that the quantities
$X_1, ...X_n$ are independent and identically distributed (IID) according to a Poisson distribution with unknown parameter $\nu \cdot \frac{y_i}{1000}$,

$$p(X_i=x_i | y_i, \nu, 1000)=Poisson(x_i| \nu \cdot \frac{y_i}{1000})$$
for i=1,...,n
Then I have a bunch of questions asking this model. Do we have a name of such model? For me, it's kind of like Poisson distribution but the parameter is random.

What is the interpretation of $\frac{y_i}{1000}$ in this model?
What is the interpretation of $\nu$ in this model?

Comment: I think "Poisson distribution with unknown parameter" sums it up. As for the question on $y_i$...well, perhaps in context the individual terms have individual meanings, but if the Poisson mean for $X_i$ is $\lambda_i$ then you are free to write $\lambda_i=\nu\times y_i\times \frac 1{1000}$ if you want to.  Hard to guess what was intended though.

Comment: $\nu$ isn't necessarily random, just unknown. As for the significance of multiplying $\nu$ by $\frac{y_i}{1000},$ I would encourage you to think about how the expected number of instances of the word "however" should vary with the length of each article, and what that means for the distributions of the $X_i.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan When the length of article is longer, then the expected number of instances of word should be larger. I only know this.

Comment: Right, but exactly how much more would the expected number of instances grow? If one article is twice as long as the other, then how many more "however"s are expected?

Comment: @StephenDonovan okay, I get your idea. If one article is twice as long, then "however" is expected to be shown up twice more. But I still don't understand the meaning of /1000 and $\nu$.

Comment: Well, in our model $\nu \cdot \frac{y_i}{1000}$ is being used for the parameter, and mean, of our Poisson variables $X_i.$ $\frac{y_i}{1000}$ isn't hard to understand, it's just the number of thousands of words in article $i.$ So, based on the idea that the means and the numbers of words (and similarly, the numbers of thousands of words) scale linearly, does that help clear up what $\nu$ is?

Comment: @StephenDonovan Sorry, I still don't understand what $\nu$ is. I know $\nu \cdot \frac{y_i}{1000}$, as a whole, is the mean of $X_i$. And I also know $\frac{y_i}{1000}$ is the number of thousands of words in article i. But I don't know what the individual $\nu$ denote.

Comment: If the mean is directly related to the length in thousands of words, $\frac{y_i}{1000},$ then it makes sense to think about the occurrences of the word "however" as having an average *rate. That's* how I would describe what $\nu$ is: the average rate of "however"s per thousand words.

Comment: @StephenDonovan great! Thank you! Can you also help me this one? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542542/ask-this-poisson-distribution-model