# Ask this Poisson distribution model

Tags: statistics

Let $X_i$ denote the quantity that captures the number of times the word *"however"* appears in the i-th article. Let’s assume that the quantities $X_1, ...X_n$ are independent and identically distributed (IID) according to a Poisson distribution with unknown parameter $\lambda$.

Question: if we model the word occurrences in each article as IID Poisson random variables with rate λ, we are implicitly assuming that the articles have the same length. why? and if that is true, what is the implied common length?

I guess the answer depends on the fact that, once we assume the model is Poisson, then both the mean and variance is fixed and the same? But I cannot give a convinced description. Also, I don't know what is the implied common length.

Comment: I believe  that word occurrences per 1000 words or some standard number of words or characters would be more appropriate.  Typical uses of Poisson consider random number of ocurrence per unit of time, space, volume, etc.

Comment: When you asked about this situation [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4542365/ask-poisson-distribution-with-random-parameters) you had different parameters for each distribution.  That seems more sensible.    Even if the lengths are the same, writing styles differ so I wouldn't expect the incidences to be equally distributed.  But, of course, for a math problem (with not pre-supposed connection to real world situations) one can assume whatever one wants.

Comment: @lulu  Yes, you are correct. The further problem will consider the writing style factor. But yes, just take this as a math problem now.